# DB synchronization on Visual Studio 2015 is hanged

Tags: visual-studio, axapta, x++, data-synchronization, dynamics-365-operations

I tried to sync database on Visual Studio 2015 after creating a project, EDT, Enum and a Table in order to create a new screen on Dynamics 365.

When I tried to synchronize it, it was stopped in the middle during schema checking process. Though it seems that the DB synchronization doesn't have problem for the first few minutes, it always stops during this process as I describe below.

Log Details:

> "Schema has not changed between new table 'DPT_TableDT' and old table
>   'DPT_TableDT' with table id '3997'. Returning from
>   ManagedSyncTableWorker.ExecuteModifyTable() Syncing Table Finished:
>   DPT_TableDT. Time elapsed: 0:00:00:00.0010010"

Could you tell me how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Full database synchronization log
[image: log]

DB Sync Log

Comment: Check if the Windows event log has any entries regarding this.Try to delete the table and then do a synchronisation.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described and also shown in your screenshot, this does not look like an error but is simply describing X++ and Dynamics AX/365FO behaviour.

When you say that it "doesn't have a problem for the first few minutes" I'm guessing you're just not being patient enough. Full database syncs should generally take between 10-30 minutes, but can take shorter or longer depending on a variety of factors such as how much horsepower your development environment has, how many changes are being sync'd etc.  I would wait *at least* one hour before considering the possibility that the sync engine has errors (or even run it overnight and see what information it has for you in the morning).

The message you've posted from the log ("Schema has not changed") isn't an error message; it is just an informational log from the sync engine. It is simply letting you know that the table did not have any changes to propagate to SQL Server.

**Solution**: Run the sync overnight and post a screenshot of the results or the error list window in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been stymied by a long running application where Access v2003 replicas refused to synchronize. The message returned was "not enough memory". This was on machines running Windows 10. The only way I was able to force synchronizing was to move the replicas onto an old machine still running Windows 98 with Office XP, which allowed synchronizing and conflict resolution. When I moved the synchronized files back to the Windows 10 machine they still would not synchronize.

I finally had to create a blank database and link to a replica, then use make-table queries to select only data fields to create new tables. I was then able to create new replicas that would synchronize.

From this I've come to suspect the following:

1. Something in Windows 10 has changed and caused the problem with synchronizing/conflict resolution.
2. Something in the hidden/protected fields added to the replica sets is seen as a problem under Windows 10 that is not a problem under Windows 98.
3. One thing I noticed is that over the years the number of replicas in the synchronizing list had grown to over 900 sets, but the only way to clear the table was to create a new clean database.